# “Could not find bundler” ruby-2.3.0

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, dashing

I am installing Dashing Dashboard on Pi3. I have "Could not find 'bundler' problem in installation steps. How can I finish the installation?

```
$ source /home/pi/.rvm/scripts/rvm
-> OK

$ rvm current
ruby-2.3.0

$ bundle
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 42 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in 'to_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in 'gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in '<main>'

$ gem install bundler
-> OK

$ bundle
-> the same problem
```

Comment: There might be something misconfigured in your system. RVM is telling you that you are using ruby-2.3.0 but in your stack trace, I see a reference to rubygems from ruby 2.1.0. Can you please provide your $PATH variable and the output of `which bundle` ?

Comment: "Removing rvm & reinstalling" solved the problem. Thank you for your kindly reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you've messed up your permissions, installing bundler into system gems by running `sudo gem install bundler`.

Delete the bundler and then install it under RVM. Double check your paths so its being installed in the RVM gem stash, not system's.

Comment: Thank you Maxim, do you mean /home/pi/.rvm folder as "under RVM"

Comment: Seems like it, you can use rvm gemdir to check where it is. After reinstalling bundler it should be in .rvm/ruby-2.3.0

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
"Removing & reinstalling" is a good idea..

I applied these steps, problem solved. 

<code>    $ rvm remove ruby-2.3.0
    -> not yet

    $ rvm uninstall ree,2.3.0
    -> OK

    $ rvm current
    system

    $ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
    -> OK

    $ sudo reboot
    -> OK

    $ source /home/pi/.rvm/scripts/rvm
    -> OK

    $ rvm current
    ruby-2.3.0

    $ cd project_name
    -> OK

    $ gem install bundler
    -> OK

    $ bundle
    -> OK </code>